# How to solve this $ (7/2)\bmod5$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I know its answer is $3\cdot5$ but I want to ask that is the following true-

$$(a/b)\bmod(p) = (a\bmod(p))\cdot((1/b)\bmod(p)))\bmod(p)$$

(where $a$ and $b$ are any integers and $p$ is a prime number.)

$(1/b)\bmod(p)$ can be solved by Euler's formula but i don't get correct answer if i solve it this way, how to solve this?

Comment: Done that way the answer is $\,1\equiv 7\cdot 3,\,$ not $\,5\cdot 3,\,$ since $\,3\equiv 2^{-1}\pmod 5\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\displaystyle7\equiv2\pmod5, \frac72=7\cdot2^{-1}\equiv2\cdot2^{-1}\pmod5\equiv1$

---

Alternatively, 
As  $\displaystyle2\cdot3\equiv1\pmod5\implies 2^{-1}\equiv3$

$\displaystyle\implies\frac72=7\cdot2^{-1}\equiv7\cdot3\equiv1\pmod5$

Comment: I know how to find $(1/2)mod(5)$ but please tell me is the equation i wrote above correct? @lab bhattacharjee

Comment: @user164013  $$ab\pmod p\equiv a\pmod p\cdot b\pmod p,$$ right?

Comment: thanks! I got my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understood what you have done but this is how i would do...

If for some $0\leq x\leq 4$ i have $\dfrac{7}{2}\mod5=x$ then see that $5$ divides $\frac{2x-7}{2}$ which implies $5$ divides $2x-7$

Check what $x$ would work in this case...

Comment: I cannot make any sense of the above. Please elaborate.

Comment: @BillDubuque : Does this make any sense to you now?

Comment: Ok, now I see. You had written $\,5/2x - 7\,$ when you meant $\,5\mid 2x-7.\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque : Yes Yes... I should have been careful :)